# How to refresh data automatically in materialized view

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

We are using postgresql and implementing materialized view. Purpose of using view is - it provides solution to refresh the data in view. Is there any way by which we can acheive automatically refresh of data on materialized view.
Note: apart from applying trigger and calling refresh on view on main table.

Comment: You need to schedule the refresh manually e.g. through a `cron` job or any of the scheduling extensions available for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

The two options you exclude (a regular table and triggers, or an explicit `REFRESH`) are the only options.